# Android, mysql, and rendering non Latin Characters as well as Latin?

Tags: java, php, mysql, android, unicode

Are these squares a representation of chinese characters being turned into unicode?

EDIT:[Here I entered the squares with numbers inside them into the post but they didn't render]

I'd like to either turn this back into the original characters when displayed in android (or to enable mysql to just store them as chinese characters not in unicode???)

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
```

While debugging it shows the strings value as
 "\u001a\u001a\u001a\u001a"

```
 byte[] bytes = chinesestringfromdatabase.getBytes();
```

turns it into 
"[26, 26, 26, 26]"

```
String fresh = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

and then this turns it back into
EDIT:[Here I entered the squares with numbers inside them into the post but they didn't render]

My phone can display chinese text.

MySQL charset:  UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

While typing my question I realize that perhaps I have the wrong charset all together.
I'm lost as to whether or not my issue will even be anything coding related or if it is just related to a setting or if php cannot handle the character set??

I'd like to store and render multiple language character sets that could contain a mixture of languages.

Answer (score 0):

> *Here I entered the squares with numbers inside them into the post but they didn't render*

With "squares with numbers inside", do you mean the same as those which you also see for some exotic languages somewhere at the bottom of the [Wikipedia homepage](http://www.wikipedia.org/), while browsing with **Firefox** browser? (in all other browsers -MSIE, Chrome, Safari, etc- you would only see nothing-saying empty squares).

If true, then it simply means that there are no glyphs available for those characters in the *font* which the webbrowser/viewer is been instructed to use.

> *I'd like to store and render multiple language character sets that could contain a mixture of languages.*

Use UTF-8 all the way. Only keep in mind that MySQL only supports the [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) panel of Unicode (max 3 bytes per character), not the other panels (4 bytes per character). So the [SMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane) panel (which contains "special" CJK characters) is out of range for MySQL.

#### References

- [PHP UTF-8 cheatsheet](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet)
- [Unicode - How to get characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) (for Java web developers)
- [MySQL reference - Unicode support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html)

Comment: [side question - How do I quote you as you quoted me]

"With "squares with numbers inside", do you mean the same as those which you also see for some exotic languages somewhere at the bottom of the Wikipedia homepage, while browsing with Firefox browser? (in all other browsers -MSIE, Chrome, Safari, etc- you would only see nothing-saying empty squares).

If true, then it simply means that there are no glyphs available for those characters in the font which the webbrowser/viewer is been instructed to use."

YES!

Comment: Just post a comment :) Well, then you need to install a proper font or to instruct the webbrowser/viewer to use a different font of which you can be certain that it has proper glyphs in its set.

Comment: I have gone into the native android browser and copied some chinese text (as a test) and then went back into my application and pasted the chinese text into an EditText form ( they are shown properly) and submitted.
From there it is sent to a php file through httppost and then it is inserted into the mysql database which in turn is read and brought to be shown in a textview, which only renders the square characters.
I'm assuming without those middle steps, if I were to just set my onclicklistener to change the textview to equal the contents of the edittext, that it would be displayed properly.

Comment: I'll try to extract the typeface that the edittext is using and apply it to my textview, and if that doesn't work i'll include my own font in an asset and try that.
Ok... using the typeface from the edittext ( that does render chinese characters properly).. I debugged and saw unique values when gettext.toString()'ing the edittext but once returned from the database each character holds a generic byte value of 26 and the squares all appear to hold the same value when inspected.. Font may have been an issue, but something is stripping what make these nonrendered characters unique, as well.

Answer (score 0):

What were the numbers in the boxes? I'm guessing they were 001A? Like ?

(SO will usually filter these out as they're ASCII control characters, typically invisible in other browsers.)

> While debugging it shows the strings value as "\u001a\u001a\u001a\u001a"

Well clearly there's no Chinese or any text to be recovered there. Any informational content in the original string has been lost.

Whilst I agree that you need to be using UTF-8 throughout (which for PHP means serving the form page with a UTF-8 `<meta>` tag, using `mysql_set_charset('utf8')`, and creating your MySQL tables with UTF-8 collations), I think you must have a more serious corruption problem than just UTF-8-vs-other-ASCII-compatible-encoding if you are somehow getting just identical control characters instead of a text string.